# Proof verification: a function with finitely many points of discontinuity is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, solution-verification, riemann-integration

I've found some proofs (on StackExchange and elsewhere) for the statement: "A function with finitely many points of discontinuity is Riemann integrable" but I've found all too much complicated as compared to the one I've come up with. Then I want to verify if what I've done is wrong or right. Can anyone verify?

---

Proof:

Let $f \in \mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}$ be a bounded function, i.e. |f(x)| < M.

Suppose $A=\{a_1, ..., a_k\}$ is the set of $k$ points of discontinuity of $f$. Let $\textbf{b}$ be a dissection (partition) such that every discontinuity point is singlely contained in an interval $I_i=[b^*_i, b^*_{i+1}]$. Let $I_p=[b_p, b_{p+1}]$ denote the $n$ intervals that doesn't contain a discontinuity point. We have that the length of each interval must be higher than 0. Let $b^*_i -  b^*_{i+1}=: \epsilon>0$. We can take the $\textbf{b}$-upper Riemann sum as (the lower is defined anagolously):

$\overline{R}_b =\sum^k_{i=1} [sup f ([b^*_{i-1}, b^*_i])]*(b^*_i - b^*_{i-1})$ + $\sum^n_{p=1} [sup f ([b_{i-1},b_i])]*(b_i - b_{i-1})$

Since we choose $\epsilon>0$ to be as small as we want, we have that as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the first term also tends to zero, since

$\sum^k_{i=1} [sup f ([b^*_{i-1},b^*_i])]*(b^*_i - b^*_{i-1}) \leq Mk\epsilon$ (and $kM$ is finite)

Since $f$ restricted to $[a,b]-A$ is uniformly continuous, it is Riemann integrable (I can use this result since it has already been proved).

---

Does this count as a valid proof?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't count as a valid proof since you use the fact that $f|_{[a,b]\setminus A}$ is uniformly continuous and therefore Riemann-integrable. This doesn't make sense, because the concept of Riemann-integrable function is defined only for functions whose domain is an interval which is closed and bounded.

There are other problems, but this one is enough.

Comment: Thanks, José. Would you mind listing the "major" problems? It would help to learn more.

Comment: @jpugliese Here are two of them. You start talking about $\varepsilon$ withou saying what it is. I assume that it is an arbitrary number greater than $0$. And I have no idea about the origin of the last inequaliy; shouldn't $M$ be on the numerator?

Comment: Yes, you are right, M should be on the numerator. It's a typo. 

About the $\epsilon$, a doubt: when I use $:=$, doesn't it means I am defining it? I tought I was defining $\epsilon$ as the length of that interval.

Comment: José, I were unable to find a reliable proof of this statement. Can you point me one that is correct? I would much appreciate it.

Comment: @jpugliese You'll find a proof in Dipak Chatterjee's *Real Analysis*. It's theorem 6.3.3 there.