# Riemann integrability of Dirichlet type functions

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $\{r_1, \dots ,r_n , \dots\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in the interval $[0, 1]$. Define, for $n\in N$ and for each $x ∈ [0, 1]$, 
$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&x \in \{r_1, · · · ,r_n\}\\
0& \mbox{otherwise,}\end{array}\right.$$ then is $f_n$ Riemann integrable on  $[0, 1]$ for each $n$?

My work: For any partition $P$ of $[0, 1]$, the subintervals contains the points $r_1,···,r_n$ thus the Riemann upper sum $U(P,f_n)$ and lower sum $L(P,f_n)$ are different.

However, can we say $\inf_PU(P,f_n)=\sup_PL(P,f_n)$ ?

Comment: Your question is the proposition to be proved in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2625670/290189

Comment: The answer to your last question is yes.

Comment: Also the problem with your work is that for an arbitrary partition there can be subintervals that contain no point in $\{r_1,\ldots, r_n\}$.  In fact, we can construct partitions where the subintervals containing such points of discontinuity can have arbitrarily small total length.